# ini4j how to indicate default values

Tags: java, ini4j

I am using [ini4j](http://ini4j.sourceforge.net/) to read a file with some property values (I couldn't use `java.util.Properties` as I wanted a two level map and INI sections come handy for that). The thing is I don't see any getters with the possibility to indicate default values, like the [java.util.Properties getters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#getProperty%28java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 0):

`org.ini4j.OptionMap` contains a method `get(Object key, String defaultValue)` that allows you to supply a default value.

Alternatively, if you're using the more specific `get(Object key, Class<T> clazz)` this also has an extension which takes `T defaultValue` as a third parameter, allowing you to provide a default value of any type (I'd make sure it matches the type of your class parameter, though!).

Javadoc can be found here: http://ini4j.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/ini4j/OptionMap.html

Answer (score 0):

When trying to initialize static fields, in my example the String `username`, I suggest the following workaround:

```
        String usrn = ini.get("User", "username");
        if(usrn == null) {
            username = "[user]";
        } else {
            username = usrn;
        }
```

ini4j's documentation is just terrible.